# Getting null when calling getSherlockActivity()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I am getting `null` while calling `getSherlockActivity();`

This is because the Activity is `finished or killed`

I could not come up with a solution to avoid in my case:

This SherlockActivity has a ViewPager with 4 Tabs.

```
adapter = new PagerAdapter((SherlockFragmentActivity) this, mViewPager);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab(), Frag1.class, bundle);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab(), Frag2.class, bundle);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab(), Frag3.class, bundle);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab(), Frag4.class, bundle);
```

When this Activity is launched, all the Tabs(Fragments) have an AsyncTask which uses `getSherlockActivity()` in `doInBackground`.

So, for all the AsyncTasks to complete, it takes around 3-5 secs, meanwhile if i press back and finish this Activity, the Last fragment **Frag4** which didn't yet started its AsyncTask(might be queued) tries for `getSherlockActivity()` and gets crashed.

I could just use a **Try-Catch block** and solve this, but is there a way i can tell the Fragments **If the parent Activity is dead, stop all your background tasks etc..** something like that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call each fragment's AsyncTask.cancel() in the Activity onDestroy() callback. That way, the asynctasks aren't going to perform anything based on the destroyed Activity context.

Comment: Yeah this can be another solution. But i have to check `isCancelled()` frequently in the `onInBackground`. It actuall contains 15-20 executions. But no other(better) solution? :(

Comment: If AsyncTask.cancel() is called, then onPostExecute() is not called anymore. Look it up in the docs.